# How to add tag to selected text, using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to add the tag for the selected text.

i have a textarea and inside i have some text entered.
So when i select some text from the text area and click code button, it should add the <code> </code> tag for the selected text...

for this i used this code:

code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formatText (tag) {
        var selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;

        if (selectedText != "") {
            var newText = "<" + tag + ">" + selectedText + "</" + tag + ">";
            document.selection.createRange().text = newText;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="my_form">
    <div id="tarea">askfashfkja;f</div><br />
    <input type="button" value="code" onclick="formatText ('code');" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

But this is not working...How can i do this???

Comment: @RobG how about div???

Comment: A JSFiddle would help here.

Comment: *Cannot call method 'createRange' of undefined* Are you familiar with web browser "developer tools"? In most browsers, press "F12" and you'll get developer tools, the "Console" tab will show javascript errors (such as the one above).

Comment: Note that simply wrapping a selection in tags isn't a general solution as other elements may be included in the selection that aren't allowed inside the element used for wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

Try the function from this example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Function to add <tag>To Selected text</tag> in textarea with id of idelm
// Receives the tag name, and the id of textarea.
// Returns the selected text, with tag
function addTagSel(tag, idelm) {
  // http://CoursesWeb.net/javascript/
  var tag_type = new Array('<', '>');        // for BBCode tag, replace with:  new Array('[', ']');
  var txta = document.getElementById(idelm);
  var start = tag_type[0] + tag + tag_type[1];
  var end = tag_type[0] +'/'+ tag +  tag_type[1];
  var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;    // this variable is false in all browsers, except IE

  if (IE) {
    var r = document.selection.createRange();
    var tr = txta.createTextRange();
    var tr2 = tr.duplicate();
    tr2.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
    tr.setEndPoint('EndToStart',tr2);
    var tag_seltxt = start + r.text + end;
    var the_start = txta.value.replace(/[\r\n]/g,'.').indexOf(r.text.replace(/[\r\n]/g,'.'),tr.text.length);
    txta.value = txta.value.substring(0, the_start) + tag_seltxt + txta.value.substring(the_start + tag_seltxt.length, txta.value.length);

    var pos = txta.value.length - end.length;    // Sets location for cursor position
    tr.collapse(true);
    tr.moveEnd('character', pos);        // start position
    tr.moveStart('character', pos);        // end position
    tr.select();                 // selects the zone
  }
  else if (txta.selectionStart || txta.selectionStart == "0") {
    var startPos = txta.selectionStart;
    var endPos = txta.selectionEnd;
    var tag_seltxt = start + txta.value.substring(startPos, endPos) + end;
    txta.value = txta.value.substring(0, startPos) + tag_seltxt + txta.value.substring(endPos, txta.value.length);

    // Place the cursor between formats in #txta
    txta.setSelectionRange((endPos+start.length),(endPos+start.length));
    txta.focus();
  }
  return tag_seltxt;
}
</script>

<form name="my_form">
    <textarea name="my_textarea" id="my_textarea">Sometext, abcd ... xyz, 123.</textarea><br />
    <input type="button" value="code" onclick="addTagSel('tag', 'my_textarea');" />
</form>
```